# SetWindowsHookEx hangs my computer

Tags: c++

Why Would SetwindowsHookEx hang my computer? My code Looks like this and it hangs ma PC

My code Looks Like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\******\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MicrosoftPackage\\x64\\Release\\chkSys.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        printf("The DLL could not be found.\n");
        getchar();
    }

        HOOKPROC addr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "chkSys");
        if (addr == NULL) {
            printf("The function was not found.\n");
            getchar();
        }

            HHOOK handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, addr, dll, 0);
            if (handle == NULL) {
                printf("The KEYBOARD could not be hooked.\n");
            }

            printf("Program successfully hooked.\nPress enter to unhook the function and stop the program.\n");
            getchar();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle);
            return 0;
}
```

What am i not doing correctly?

Comment: I suggest you ditch your (somewhat weird) background story and focus on the programming problem. You didn't describe what the program should do and how it fails

Comment: show chkSys.dll code,  is chkSys is an api inside chkSys.dll?

Comment: @Balu yes, just a function to log URLs thats all

Comment: Please show the `chkSys` code. You may have incorrect function signature, not calling original hook proc, your DLL may do illegal things in `DllMain()` and so on. There's a lot that can go wrong in a "simple" system-wide hook.

Comment: That getchar() call isn't that likely to work when you fumble the hook callback.  And worse, injecting *every* process with a buggy hook turns the keyboard into a pizza.  You'll have to start small, start with one victim first, a test program you can afford to have misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid that. When you are hooking keyboard events globally and then you start debugging your code, it will block notifications from keyboard. For this you either have to do remote debugging or you can't debug, just let the app run in release mode and write logs in a file for debugging.
Also you can change timeout for keyboard hook here:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LowLevelHooksTimeout setting

Comment: In other words , instead of WH_KEYBOARD what can i use to do global DLL injection? any ideas?

Comment: First of all seems like you are trying to develop a keylogger. What are you trying to do ? Alternative method is GetAsyncKeyState

Comment: No, No keyloggers here

Answer (score 0):

Per the [KeyboardProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984.aspx) documentation:

> This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**

Your code does not have a message loop.  You are hooking every running process, so all input-active processes are going to be trying to forward keyboard messages to your app, but it is not processing any of those messages.

If you want to block your app until the user presses a key to satisfy `getchar()`, then call `SetWindowsHookEx()` in a worker thread, and give that thread a message loop.